# Vertically center-align col text with background color in bootstrap 4.1

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

this is the code that works actually aligns the text in the middle:

```
<div class="container section-content">
    <div class="row" style="border-radius: 4px; border: solid 1px #979797;">
        <div class="col-md-3 align-self-center" style="background-color: #4a90e2">
            Align
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but this is the output:
[image]
**the desired output should fill the whole left column with the background color.**

how do i achieve this?

edit: not a duplicate of [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)
this is an issue with vertical alignment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="background-color: #4a90e2;">
      Align
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This helped. The solution that worked based on your code: `<div class="col-md-3 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="background-color: #4a90e2">`

Comment: Glad to help, please accept the answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.
ps: see full page output. Use this class `align-items-center`

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 </head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="border-radius: 4px; border: solid 1px #979797;">
        <div class="col-md-3 align-items-center" style="background-color: #4a90e2">
            <h1>Align</h1>
        </div>
  <div class="col-md-9"><ul>
  <li>content</li>
  <li>content</li>
   </ul></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "align" content should be inside an inner div that's centered, instead of centering the column itself.

```
<div class="container section-content">
    <div class="row" style="border-radius: 4px; border: solid 1px #979797;">
        <div class="col-md-3 d-flex flex-column" style="background-color: #4a90e2">
            <div class="my-auto">
            Align
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/fwlfC2eCh7